# imageLabel isn't appearing in jBox

Tags: jbox

I'm working on a application that uses jBox. So far I like the interface, it's very simple and very clean. The problem I'm running into is, I have some images that require attributions to be included. I'd really like to include that when you click the image.

I'm using the code:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    var options = {
      imageLabel: 'My title'
    };
    new jBox("Image", options);
});

</script>

<a href="img1.jpg" data-jbox-image="gal1" imageLabel="test" class="demo-img1"><img src="img1.jpg" alt="test1" title="test2"></a>

<a href="img1.jpg" data-jbox-image="gal1" imageLabel="test" class="demo-img1"><img src="img1.jpg" alt="test1" title="test2"></a>
```

When I click on the image, the modal opens great, but I can't see any text associated with it. I've tried filling in all the blanks that I thought it might come from, but so far, I've had no luck at all. The image type isn't super defined on the documentation, so maybe I'm looking for an effect that isn't going to happen.

I'd really like to see my image along with some text, as long as I can control the text for each image individually, I'll be happy!

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the name of the attribute for the option `imageLabel`. See more here: https://stephanwagner.me/jBox/options#options-image

I'd also use the attribute with `data-` in front just to make it HTML conform.

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    var options = {
      imageLabel: 'data-label'
    };
    new jBox("Image", options);
});

</script>

<a href="img1.jpg" data-jbox-image="gal1" data-label="test" class="demo-img1"><img src="img1.jpg" alt="test1" title="test2"></a>

<a href="img1.jpg" data-jbox-image="gal1" data-label="test" class="demo-img1"><img src="img1.jpg" alt="test1" title="test2"></a>
```